# Preserve original column name in pd.get_dummies()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of columns whose values are all strings. I need to one hot encode them with `pd.get_dummies()`.

I want to keep the original name of those columns along with the value.
So lets say I have a column named `Street`, and its values are `Paved` and `Not Paved`.
After running `get_dummies()`, I would like the 2 resulting columns to be entitled `Street_Paved` and `Street_Not_Paved`. Is this possible? Basically the format for the `prefix` parameter is `{i}_{value}`, with `i` referring to the `for i in cols` common nomenclature.

My code is:

```
cols = ['Street', 'Alley', 'CentralAir', 'Utilities', 'LandSlope', 'PoolQC']
pd.get_dummies(df, columns = cols, prefix = '', prefix_sep = '')
```

Comment: Can you add some example of data and expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If remove `prefix = '', prefix_sep = ''` parameters get default `prefix` from columns names with default separator `_`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Street' : ['Paved','Paved','Not Paved','Not Paved'],
                   'Alley':list('acca')})


cols = ['Street','Alley']

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = cols)

print (df)
   Street_Not Paved  Street_Paved  Alley_a  Alley_c
0                 0             1        1        0
1                 0             1        0        1
2                 1             0        0        1
3                 1             0        1        0
```

If need replace all spaces by `_` add rename:

```
cols = ['Street','Alley']
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = cols).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))

print (df)
   Street_Not_Paved  Street_Paved  Alley_a  Alley_c
0                 0             1        1        0
1                 0             1        0        1
2                 1             0        0        1
3                 1             0        1        0
```

Comment: wow way easier than i thought, thanks!